# The implementation of the text selection functional does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, create-react-app

I have a huge problem with highlighting text on selection, I can make the test selected using the `onMouseUp` event and the browser API `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0`)
I get the coordinates of the text that 
 I am highlighting and it is highlighted correctly, for this I use the following implementation.

```js
const {useState}=React;

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('Some text will be here but this one will be yellow'),
        [start, setStart] = useState(0),
        [end, setEnd] = useState(0)

  const onMouseUp = ()=> {
    let data = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
    setStart(data.startOffset)
    setEnd(data.endOffset)
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <div className='textContent'>
          {text.slice(0, start)}
          <span className="selected">{text.slice(start, end)}</span>
          {text.slice(end)}
      </div> 
      
      <div className='textContent' onMouseUp={onMouseUp}>
          {text}
      </div> 
    </div>
  )
}



const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.selected{
  background: #f00;
}

.App{
  position: relative;
}

.textContent{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

My code works great in codesandbox but when I start create-react-app application it works not correct and after dbl click and another action I see not correct selection and so on, why it happens?

[Here is link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-mcnulty-pzh1b?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: It seems to be working? Turns purple on double click, and red when it loses focus? What is your intended result?

Comment: Yes it works in codesandbox but dont work when I add it to empty create-react-app aplication, I update question, in create-reat-app when I have problem with dblClick selection

Comment: I am curious why you're not using the [`::selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection#result) pseudo-element here though.

Comment: because I need save marks afterreload and after some action

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in updating the chrome browser, after the update it passed, apparently the chrome community thus speeds up the update for users)